# Evaluating the $n$th derivative of $(1+x+...+x^n)^d$ at $x=0$

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, multinomial-coefficients

I am trying to evaluate

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)^d\Bigr|_{x=0}.$$

If one starts deriving directly (or after summing the geometric series) the number of terms gets doubled every time you derive. My approach was the following. We can write

$$(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)^d=c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+...+c_{n\cdot d}z^{n\cdot d}.$$

The $n$th derivative of this will have the form

$$c'_n+c'_{n+1}z^{n+1}+...+c'_{n\cdot d}z^{n\cdot d},$$

so evaluating at $z=0$ is the same as computing $c'_n$, which

$$c'_n=c_n\cdot n\cdot(n-1)\cdot...\cdot2=c_n\cdot n!.$$

Using the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) we have

$$(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)^d=\sum_{k_0+k_1+...+k_n=d}{d \choose k_0,k_1,...,k_n}\prod_{t=0}^nz^{t\cdot k_t}.$$
Now

$$\prod_{t=0}^nz^{t\cdot k_t} = z^{\sum_{t=0}^nt\cdot k_t},$$

so we need $k_t$ such that $\sum_{t=0}^nt\cdot k_t=n$, or $\sum_{t=1}^nt\cdot k_t=n$ and $k_0=d-(k_1+...+k_n)$. Then, $c_n$ will be the the multinomial coefficient where

$$k_1+2k_2+3k_3+...+nk_n=n.$$

I am stuck here, since there are many combinations of $k_t$ that satisfy the previous equality. Any help on how to proceed, or a different way to approach this will be appreciated.

Comment: @LionHeart Upright $\mathrm{d}$ is derivative, normal $d$ is is the exponent. Maybe I should have used another letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This $n$-th derivative is $n!$ times the $x^n$-coefficient of
$$f(x)=(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)^d.$$
But compare this coefficient to that of
$$g(x)=(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n+x^{n+1}+\cdots)^d=\frac1{(1-x)^d}.$$
These coefficients are the same, since the extra terms don't affect the powers
of $x$ up to $x^n$. But, by the binomial theorem, say,
$$g(x)=(1-x)^{-d}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+d-1}{d-1}x^n.$$
Your derivative is thus
$$n!\binom{n+d-1}{d-1}=\frac{(n+d-1)!}{(d-1)!}$$